# OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid. [Python]

Tags: python, tkinter, pystray

Hey i am trying to make a application working in windows. It's basically adjusting your monitor brightness. There is a function provides minimize application. So i have issue about minimize.

When clicking second time to minimize button getting error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Python_simple_projects\Desktop_brightness_app\test.py", line 249, in minimize_app
    self.icon.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 212, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 120, in _run
    self._hwnd = self._create_window(self._atom)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 244, in _create_window
    hwnd = win32.CreateWindowEx(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pystray\_util\win32.py", line 204, in _err
    raise ctypes.WinError()
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid.
```

There is a few part of code below:

```py
import ttkbootstrap as tb
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import PIL.Image
import pystray


class DesktopBrightnessApp:
     def __init__(self):
            self.minimize_button = tb.Button(self.root, text="Minimize", 
               command=self.minimize_app)
               self.minimize_button.place(x=215, y=200)

            self.icon = pystray.Icon('icon', img, menu=pystray.Menu(
                pystray.MenuItem("Open GUI", self.on_move_clicked),
                pystray.MenuItem("Exit", self.on_move_clicked)
                ))

     def on_move_clicked(self, icon, item):

            if str(item) == "Open GUI":
               icon.stop()
               self.root.deiconify()

            elif str(item) == "Exit":
               icon.stop()
               self.root.destroy()

     def minimize_app(self):
            self.root.withdraw()
            self.icon.run()
        

     def run(self):
         self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = DesktopBrightnessApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: And i want to add some information a few days ago the code working fine and I can say certainty there is no major changes in code.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `icon.stop()` is executed, you need to create a new instance of `pystray.Icon` in order to run `icon.run()`:

```py
class DesktopBrightnessApp:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # convert img to instance variable self.img
        self.img = ...

        ...
        # create the icon menu once
        self.menu = pystray.Menu(
            pystray.MenuItem("Open GUI", self.on_move_clicked),
            pystray.MenuItem("Exit", self.on_move_clicked)
        )
        # don't create instance of pystray.Icon here

    ...
    def minimize_app(self):
        self.root.withdraw()
        # create instance of pystray.Icon here
        self.icon = pystray.Icon('icon', self.img, menu=self.menu)
        self.icon.run()

    ...
```

Comment: Hey @acw1668  I am getting error now:

```TypeError: unicode string expected instead of Menu instance```

Comment: @Zephyrus Answer updated.  Keyword argument `menu` should be used when calling `pystray.Icon(...)`.

Comment: Thanks to responding again it worked! I accepted your answer as a solution @acw1668

Answer (score -1):

i recommend using ctypes (im pretty sure its already installed.)

Comment: `cpython` is a standard library so it comes with every installation of python but how do you recommend that OP fix their problem? Their issue is most likely caused by unwanted interactions between `pystray` and `tkinter`.

Comment: Hey @user23103381, there is not a part to need to use **ctypes**. I think issue about **pystray** or **tkinter**.

Comment: Answers are not for recommendation, it should rather be a comment. Once you earn enough reputation you'll be able to leave comments on posts